# Android: How to show a graph for every minutes values

Tags: android, graph

I am making one application like share market. I want to show graph for every minutes changes in price for share. I tried time series line graph of MPAndroidChart.

But it is look like:
[MPAndroidChare Line graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oB3M0.png)

But I want to show data like:

[I want to show like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocXPv.png)

Which library should i use?

Answer (score 0):

You can show such data using handler. I show you a sample code..

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Handler starter, repeater;
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Do whatever  in this space it will loop until the app pauses and resume when app resume
        // and update this space at an interval of one minute

        repeater.postDelayed(this, 60000);
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    starter = new Handler();
    repeater = new Handler();
    starter.post(r);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    repeater.removeCallbacks(r);
    super.onPause();
}
}
```